# CROSS APPLY to JOIN tables that are not related

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I noticed that the `CROSS APPLY` is used normally for functions but I used it in the following way:

```
SELECT pu.UserID UserID,  A.AlertID 
FROM tbl_Users pu
CROSS APPLY 
(Select AlertID from tbl_Alerts) A
```

Essentially for each user, I wanted to have it show the 2 alert that are in the tbl_Alerts table.

As such it would show somehting like:

```
    UserID    AlertID
    1         1 
    1         2
    2         1
    2         2
    3         1
    3         2
```

Wondering if this is a legitimate use of `CROSS APPLY` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is only going to return one user id.

Is it legitimate?  I think this is much simpler:

```
SELECT pu.UserID UserID,  A.AlertID 
FROM tbl_Users pu 
     CROSS JOIN tbl_Alerts A
WHERE pu.Userid = @UserID;
```

But your code is correct SQL.

Comment: Thank you. As both work fine when would I use a cross apply?

Comment: @NatePet . . . `CROSS APPLY` implements a `LATERAL JOIN`, which is a more general type of `JOIN`.  It is used when you need a lateral join or want to call a table-valued function.